# JAVA incompatible types ... "cannot be converted to"

Tags: java

When trying to compile the following code, I get the error:

```
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/Oefeningen/3/Opdracht 2/programmeren_ex-adreslijst-java/src/main/java/be/uantwerpen/AdresLijst.java:[39,16] incompatible types: java.util.ArrayList<be.uantwerpen.Adres> cannot be converted to be.uantwerpen.AdresLijst
```

I'm unsure what this exactly means and thus how to fix it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Please ignore the dutch names, they're not important.

```
package be.uantwerpen;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdresLijst implements AdresLijstIf {

    private String naam;
    public ArrayList<Adres> adressen;
    public ArrayList<Adres> result;

    public AdresLijst(String naam) {
        this.naam = naam;
        this.adressen = new ArrayList<Adres>();
    }

    public String getNaam() {
        return naam;
    }

    public void adresToevoegen(Adres adres) {
        this.adressen.add(adres);
    }

    public void adresVerwijderen(Adres adres) {
        this.adressen.remove(adres);
    }

    public int aantalAdressen() {
        System.out.println("Er zitten " + adressen.size() + " adressen in deze lijst");
    }

    public AdresLijst zoekNaam(String query) {
        result = new ArrayList<Adres>();
        for(Adres adres : adressen) {
            if(adres.getNaam().startsWith(query) == true) {
                this.result.add(adres);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: `result` is `ArrayList<Adres>`, but the method declares to return a `AdresLijst`.

Comment: As luk said, the type you return from your method's body (`ArrayList<Adres>`) is different from the one you have set in your definition (`AdresLijst`). You have to change one of them according to your desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

let's not disregard dutch names as unimportant :) I do speak it and that made it a lot easier to understand what your code is trying to do. Which is why you should attempt to write method names in english if you can; it'll be a lot more familiar to other programmers.

### The problem

In your `zoekNaam` method, the return type is declared as `AdresLijst`. Whilst conceptually a `List<Adres>` sure sounds like an AdresLijst, the compiler doesn't know that, and the typing system doesn't work that way: It's guns and grandmas as far as the compiler is concerned (they are completely unrelated; a `List<Adres>` is not an `AdresLijst`, and an `AdresLijst` is not a `List<Adres>`, and neither can be converted to the other automatically).

So, when you `return result;` in that method, with result being a `List<Adres>`, the compiler is complaining: Nope - you need to return an `AdresLijst`, and not a `List<Adres>`.

### How to fix this

Option 1 is to make a new `AdresLijst` object and set up its `result` field with the appropriate stuff. But that's probably not a good idea:

You have a more fundamental design issue. Your fields are the state of your AdresLijst. Your `zoekNaam` call **changes this state** - it modifies the `result` field. That means a search is not 'fleeting' - a search modifies the list.

Except, you don't actually use this state anywhere. The right move is a bit more convoluted:

You need to first get rid of that `result` field; it should not be part of the state of a list (it's a 'fleeting' aspect: Some code calls `zoekNaam`, and gets a result back. It's not up to the code of AdresLijst to remember the result, whomever called you has the job of taking the results and storing them, or printing them, or express them in interpretive dance form - it's not your job to worry about what they do with it. Your job is just to run the search and provide the results).

Then, either change the return type to `List<Adres>`, or, make a new `AdresLijst` object and initialize its `adressen` value with your search result:

```
// now that result is no longer a field, make a local var instead:
List<Adres> result = new ArrayList<Adres>();
// ... rest of your zoekNaam, but remove 'return result;'

// and now we make a new AdresLijst object,
// give it a proper name..
AdresLijst out = new AdresLijst(this.naam + " (Zoekresultaten)");

// add all our results to it...
out.adressen.addAll(result);

// and return it
return out;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanataion. I understand that writing in English would be easier, but this is for an assignment in class, so I chose the names as given in the assignment.

Your solution was very clear, I understand my mistake.

Comment: Quick follow up: in the tests added for the assignment, a new error comes up. It's no longer a compilation error though.

_java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.ArrayList.add(Object)" because "this.result" is null_ 
At line 39: `this.result.add(adres);`

Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't do what I told you to do - `this.result` explicitly refers to the field `result` (right at the top). That fields need to be removed. Then just call that thing `result`.

Comment: Aah, yes. You're right, because of the 'this.', it skipped the local variable. It works now indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature `public AdresLijst zoekNaam(String query)` should return a `AdresLijst` but returns a `ArrayList<Adres>`.
You should either change method signature to :

```java
public ArrayList<Adres> zoekNaam(String query)
```

Either change the returned value with the type you need.

Comment: `return this;` is not a proper answer here. It makes the compiler errors go away, but then the zoekNaam method doesn't do anything observable (it searches; the search results would be completely inaccessible). Maybe the dutch names threw you off :)